# Create and order in ascending order a column

Tags: dplyr, mutate

i need to create a new column that is a copy of the already existing 'Engagement' column that I have. That new column (named Hello) needs to be ordered in two categories divided by the mean (8 values above the mean and in the other category the 8 values under the mean). I tried using the functions mutate and arrange of the dplyr package, but nothing has worked so far. I get the error code : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')" when i try the code :

```
mutate (classe_df, Hello, Engagement)
```

My code has 16 values, where the engagement column is made of the likes divided by the views.

Here is my complete code :

```
Sujet <- sprintf("s_%d", 1:16)

Titre <- c("Coffee cake cookies", "Poutine baloney", "Polite Boy","Infinity water glitch", "Garlic  butter steak bites", "Sun Conure", "Pizza in my room", "Parkour skills", "Supercars", "Brown monster", "Batch of pasta", "Police grappler", "F340", "Ceramic brakes", "GT3 Seat Solution", "Over Priced GT2RS" )

Likes <- c(150700, 11200, 3500000, 256700, 1400000, 791300, 439900, 382700, 45400, 1300000, 246200, 32200, 319000, 1892, 3413, 17400)

Vues <- c(1300000, 214500, 13500000, 11400000, 17100000, 6700000, 400000, 11300000, 203100, 18400000, 3000000, 1000000, 1800000, 12600, 23500, 213800)


Engagement <- c(150700 / 1300000, 11200 / 214500, 3500000 / 13500000, 256700 / 11400000, 1400000 /         17100000, 791300 / 6700000, 439900 / 4000000, 382700 / 11300000, 45400 / 203100, 1300000 / 18400000, 246200 / 3000000, 32200 / 1000000, 319000 / 1800000, 1892 / 12600, 3413 / 23500, 17400 / 213800)


classe_df <- data.frame(Sujet, Titre, Likes, Vues, Engagement)

#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(classe_df, aes(x = Vues, y = Likes) ) +
geom_point() +
labs(x = 'Vues', y = 'Likes', title = 'Relation entre les likes et les vues') +
theme_light()

ggsave("ggplot.jpg",
   scale = 1,
   width = 10,
   height = 7,
   units = "cm",
   dpi = 300)


#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

Comment: First, @Sam, welcome to stack overflow! A question about your data: tell us about why some values are separated by comma whereas some are separated by backslash. This will allow us to understand your df accurately. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, you probably are trying to apply the mutate function to a vector of data instead to a dataframe. Are you sure you are applying mutate a column of the dataframe, and not to a vector?

Comment: Hi Sam, it is better to provide the whole dataframe, instead of just one column. Also, it helps us to help you if you add the code that you used that resulted in the error message!

Comment: It's a normal dash, to express a division because i didn't know how to do it otherwise. There are therefore 16 values, separated by commas. Number are likes per videos divided by views per videos, to have the engagement rate.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but can you please explain which numbers are what? For example: you've got `(150700 / 1300000, 11200 /...)`. I think you're saying these numbers belong in three different columns, but which is which?

Comment: I edited the post to make everything more clear. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after, @Sam?

**Updated In Light of Sam's Edit**

```
Sujet <- sprintf("s_%d", 1:16)

Titre <- c("Coffee cake cookies", "Poutine baloney", "Polite Boy","Infinity water glitch", "Garlic  butter steak bites", "Sun Conure", "Pizza in my room", "Parkour skills", "Supercars", "Brown monster", "Batch of pasta", "Police grappler", "F340", "Ceramic brakes", "GT3 Seat Solution", "Over Priced GT2RS" )

Likes <- c(150700, 11200, 3500000, 256700, 1400000, 791300, 439900, 382700, 45400, 1300000, 246200, 32200, 319000, 1892, 3413, 17400)

Vues <- c(1300000, 214500, 13500000, 11400000, 17100000, 6700000, 400000, 11300000, 203100, 18400000, 3000000, 1000000, 1800000, 12600, 23500, 213800)

Engagement <- c(150700 / 1300000, 11200 / 214500, 3500000 / 13500000, 256700 / 11400000, 1400000 /         17100000, 791300 / 6700000, 439900 / 4000000, 382700 / 11300000, 45400 / 203100, 1300000 / 18400000, 246200 / 3000000, 32200 / 1000000, 319000 / 1800000, 1892 / 12600, 3413 / 23500, 17400 / 213800)


classe_df <- data.frame(Sujet, Titre, Likes, Vues, Engagement)

library(dplyr)
classe_df <- classe_df %>%
  mutate(Hello = ifelse(median(Engagement) > Engagement, "below", "above"))
```

Using `dplyr` I created a column that looks into `classe_df$Engagement`, determines the median, and returns either "above" or "below" depending on the value's relation to the median value (half are, of course, above the median while the rest are below). If this answers your question, please kindly mark this reply correct/accepted. If it doesn't, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure, because the new column created need to order the videos in 2 categories based on the MEDIAN (not mean.. my fault). But even if I change the code mean to median, the values are still not in order... Everything is good except the fact that the values of the column Hello are not ordered by the median

Comment: Switching `mean` for `median` is simple. But can you help me understand what you mean by "ordered by the median"? Why does the order in which the lines of your `df` appear matter? Also, are you saying `Hello` should simply say "above" or "below" instead of be a numerical value specifying relation to the median of `Engagement`?

Comment: Yeah, I think I wasn't clear enough, but the column Hello should say something close to "above" or "below", relating to the median of Engagement. Two distinct words

Comment: Updated answer in light of your update, @Sam

Comment: Thank you so much, everything looks so good!

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could add a percentage sign after every data in the engagement column (only this one).

Comment: @Sam, what would you like it to be the percentage of?

Comment: go look at the last comment on my other post if you want to understand.